# Java Scanner.nextLine() consumes newline character

Tags: java, regex

I have a scanner set up that is working on an InputStream.

I am using Scanner.nextLine() to advance to each line, then doing some regular expression work on each line.

I have a regular expression that is basically like `[\w\p{Z}]+?[;\n\r]` to pick up anything to the end of that line, or just ONE thing, if they are semi-colon delimited.

so if my InpustStream looks like

```
abcd;
xyz
```

It will pick up abcd;, but not xyz.

I think this is because scanner is consuming the newline character at the end of the line of text must be getting consumed somehow when the .nextLine() function is being called. Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

As an additional point of info, for my regex, i am compiling the pattern with Pattern.DOTALL

Thanks!

Comment: Are you obliged to only use a regex for this? Seems that a `String.split` could do the trick as well?

Comment: really easy to find out - stop regexing on each line and check what nextLine() is getting...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, you're the one that's causing the problem, by trying to consume a newline at the end of the last line. :-/  It's perfectly valid for the last line to end abruptly without a newline character, but your regex requires it to have one.  You might be able to fix that by replacing the newline with an anchor or a lookahead, but there are much easier ways to go about this.

One is to override the default delimiter and iterate over the fields with `next()`:

```
Scanner sc1 = new Scanner("abcd;\nxyz");
sc1.useDelimiter("[;\r\n]+");
while (sc1.hasNext())
{
  System.out.printf("%s%n", sc1.next());
}
```

The other is to iterate over the lines with `nextLine()` (using the default delimiter) and then split each line on semicolons:

```
Scanner sc2 = new Scanner("abcd;\nxyz");
while (sc2.hasNextLine())
for (String item : sc2.nextLine().split(";"))
{
  System.out.printf("%s%n", item);
}
```

Scanner's API is one of the most bloated and unintuitive I've ever worked with, but you can greatly reduce the pain of using it if you remember these two crucial points:

1. Think in terms of matching the *delimiters*, not the fields (like you do with String's `split()`).
2. Never call one of the `nextXXX()` methods without first calling the corresponding `hasNextXXX()` method.

Answer (score 2):

So, why don't you add a newline to your `nextLine()` result?

Isn't there a Regex-Special-Character `^` or `$` that stands for the strings bounds?

Comment: Although this is more kind of a vague answer, I do agree with it. You could add a `\r` character at the end of the string. Or just do a regex on the complete string (don't use a scanner). That will return all line endings.

Comment: THe strings are too large to regex on the entire thing at once

Answer (score 1):

The regex character `$` finds "the end of the pattern". Having said that since you don't have the end of the line character, it's easy to consume everything up until the first semi-colon; just consume everything other than semicolon:

```
[^;]+
```

`Scanner` consumes the newline character as part of its behaviour because you don't usually want to deal with it, and it's system-dependent.

Edit: In a comment someone pointed out you could just use `line.split(";")` and grab the first value. This would work too.

Answer (score 1):

The API clearly specifies that next line removes any line separator [nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)

you can do one of the various suggestions in the other replies. But also please notice that scanner has methods with "pattern". so if your regex is correct, you can use the following methods:

[hasNext(Pattern pattern)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29)   or [hasNext(String pattern)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28java.lang.String%29) to find if you have more tokens

and then

[next(Pattern pattern)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29) or [next(String pattern)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28java.lang.String%29) to get the token if the above returned true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\z` in your regex pattern to denote the end of the input, or `$` for the end of the line. Furthermore, `Scanner.nextLine()` by default returns the line *without* the newline character. Also, you could change the delimiters used by your `Scanner` to include `;` with its `useDelimiter` method. Lastly, your pattern might not do what you think it does as `\p{Z}` only catches letters 'Z' judging by the [documentation for `Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: You are misinterpreting the documentation. See this link: http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

Comment: No,  `\p{Z}` is a genuine Unicode category, it's just totally useless.  It includes `\p{Zl}` (LINE SEPARATOR, U+2028), `\p{Zp}` (PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR, U+2029), and `\p{Zs}` (SPACE SEPARATOR, [list](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm)), but **not** `\n` or `\r`.  There is no Unicode category for the characters people actually use to separate lines and/or paragraphs.

Comment: Well, yes, but you do the regex matching in Java, right? When using `Pattern`, shouldn't you use the Java regex syntax?